# Setting utf8mb4 permanently for GCP CloudSQL instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

To allow multi-byte characters (e.g., emojis) to be written to various columns, I'm using SET NAMES utf8mb4; to set the character set and various other server settings for a GCP CloudSQL instance.

The issue is that the setting is not permanent if I run it as a SQL command. How can I make it permanent (even on restart of the instance)? I have set one flag (character_set_server), but that wasn't enough. Do I need to add a bunch of flags?

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#config) the DB's flags by editing the Cloud SQL instance and going to Add database flags > Add item.

In your case, add the item `character_set_server` and select `utf8mb4` from the drop-down list. Remember that a restart is needed in order for the changes to take effect.

You can find a list of the supported flags [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags).

Comment: thx. I just checked to be sure. that's the flag I already set (and restarted) but it wasn't enough.

Comment: @beachCode Sorry, I misread the part where you said you already have set `character_set_server`. Are you using MySQL 5.6 or 5.7?

Comment: @beachCode If the MySQL version is 5.7, try also setting character_set_system, character_set_client, and collaction_connection to the same value.

Comment: No problem, you didn’t miss it. I hadn’t mentioned it by name—that was an edit. It’s 5.7. I’ll try setting those in the morning. Thanks again

Comment: @beachCode Alright, let me know the outcome once you've had time to make changes.

Comment: hey I checked. Those flags are not available in the CloudSQL options. Only character_set_server is listed.

Comment: @beachCode Yes, you are correct on that, my apologies. I found a good Medium article that describes the whole procedure, including all changes you need to do in the MySQL configuration for enabling Emojis: https://medium.com/google-cloud/enable-full-unicode-in-mysql-on-google-cloud-aaa2635486d6.

Comment: @beachCode Since I don't know what configuration you've already made to the Cloud SQL instance, and at which point is it failing, I believe it's better if you have a look at that article and follow the steps in it. It would be even better if you do it in a new Cloud SQL instance from scratch, so you are assured that no other previous configuration is conflicting with it.

Comment: I've seen that Medium post, it didn't help. I still haven't found the solution. The changes work but are reverted by something. I'm not sure what's resetting them. It's not me manually restarting the server.

Comment: @beachCode any luck with this?